# regex to change a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a translation project, when user types i have to change some words like

**"yalama"->"yaLama"**,

**"yalamak"->"yaLamak"**,

**"kalamadi"->"kaLamadi"**,

**"salamadi"->"saLamadi"**,

My code works well for now but i have a problem: if i type only **"Lam"**, it is changing to **"Lm"** its okay.. But if i type **"aLamsiz"** ( i mean any **"xxxLamxxx.."** ) not working :(

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

var text2 = $(this).val();

text2 = text2.replace(/al/g, "L");

text2 = text2.replace(/([^L]|^)am/g, '$1m');

text2 = text2.replace(/\bLam\b/g, "Lm");
 
$("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just this regex would suffice.

```
text = text.replace(/a[lL]a/g, "aLa");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your full translator is trying to do but to get the original mapping you only have to add an 'a' to the first regex.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

var text2 = $(this).val();

text2 = text2.replace(/al/g, "aL");

text2 = text2.replace(/([^L]|^)am/g, '$1m');

text2 = text2.replace(/\bLam\b/g, "Lm");
 
$("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: i can't add an "a" because i use another alphabet and im using its character code :/

Comment: You should give us all the rules or the answer will never be accurate ;)